# How to Set the First Value to Table to Colour

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have sorted an Array in Ascending order. I need to display the first value of the table to be colored. How can I do this

My code is :

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"isDefault"  ascending:NO];
sortedArray = [beneficiariesArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
NSLog(@"This is Sorted Array %@",sortedArray);


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath

{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];    
    if (cell == nil)
    {    
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];    
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Fullname"];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set it by use of [**`indexPath.row`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765730/nsindexpath-item-vs-nsindexpath-row/14765781#14765781) in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Replace with following code :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath

{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];    
    if (cell == nil)
    {    
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];    
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    if(indexPath.row == 0)
     cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; // set color as you want.

    cell.textLabel.text = [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Fullname"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i did this but the values  disappears after i scroll

Comment: @VMC501 - which value ?? and also tableView is scrollable hope you know about it.

Comment: the first values disapprears . it looks fine when i dont scroll

Comment: Mate first read [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), It is default behavior of it.

Comment: is there any solution for it ?

Comment: @patel. i know its scrollable. when i scroll down, and go to the top again. the text in the first row is empty

Comment: Set `NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row]`

Answer (score 2):

```
Here it try it in cellForRowAtIndexPath
if(indexPath.row == row number)
{
cell.backGroundColor = [UIColor anycolor]; // set color as you want.
}
```

in row number provide the value where you want the color to be displayed and in anycolor type the colorname available.

Answer (score 1):

At `cellForRowAtIndexPath` Method. To set color for the first value .

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView )tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath

{

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)

{
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

}
if(indexPath.row==0)
{
cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor greenColor];
// or you can set background as cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Fullname"]; return cell;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath

{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    if (indexPath.section ==0 && indexPath.row == 0) {

        // do your stuff.

        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    }else{

        // normal stuff

        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }


    cell.textLabel.text = [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Fullname"];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have connected your table view delegate and datasource.
2. In your cellForRowAtIndexPath use this.

   if(indexPath.row==0)

   cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor redColor];

Answer (score 1):

There is a property for visible cells.

so you can set the color of the first cell always.

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath

{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];    
    if (cell == nil)
    {    
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];    
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    [[tableView.visibleCells objectAtIndex:0] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; //This line changes color for first visible cell
    [[tableView.visibleCells objectAtIndex:1] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; //This line clears the color of second cell if scrolling in upward direction.

    cell.textLabel.text = [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Fullname"];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply check the cell Index value like this :

```
if (indexPath.row == 0)
{
     // Place your logic
}
```