# Array count minus array count

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

How can I show array count minus array count? I have two arrays like this:

```
var likedBy = [NSArray]()
var dislikedBy = [NSArray]()
```

And I am trying to get the count as a string on UITextLabel like this:

```
imageCell.likeLabel.text = self.likedBy.count - self.dislikedBy.count
```

But I get error:

> No "-" candidates produce the expected contextual result type
>   "String?"

Any suggestions?

Comment: String(self.likedBy.count - self.dislikedBy.count)

Comment: hint: count is a _number_ the text is a _string_.

Comment: Suggestion #1: *Read* the error message. – Suggestion #2: If you get compiler errors that you don't understand, *split* the expression into multiple statements: `let diff = self.likedBy.count - self.dislikedBy.count; imageCell.likeLabel.text = diff`. You should see the problem now!

Answer (score 3):

You should use string interpolation with `\()` because `count` property returns `Int` and you need a `String` to set the `text` property:

```
imageCell.likeLabel.text = "\(self.likedBy.count - self.dislikedBy.count)"
```

Comment: Thanks! Quick question - In the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` - what is difference between indexPath.row and indexPath.item?

Comment: `item`: An index number identifying an item in a section of a collection view.

Comment: Browse through http://stackoverflow.com/a/14765781/2035845 for more info on indexpath.item vs indexpath.row!!

Answer (score 2):

replace your line

```
imageCell.likeLabel.text = "\(self.likedBy.count - self.dislikedBy.count)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to write an extension on NSArray to provide a element count difference so your code is cleaner and the responsibilities lie in the right place. As in, your main code flow is not interested in working out the difference between two array counts, it wants to know how many likes there are left, after the dislikes have been subtracted.

```
extension NSArray {
    func elementCountDiff(array: NSArray) -> Int {
        return self.count - array.count
    }
}

...

imageCell.likeLabel.text = String(self.likedBy.elementCountDiff(self.dislikedBy))
```