# Animate selected row on button tap

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uianimation

I currently have a table with a custom cell that contains a button and a label. Everything is working fine, the label displays the product name and the button responds to a button tap.

What I would like to be able to do is animate the width of the row/cell where the button was tapped.

Here is the code I currently have...

**Main ViewController:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reusableCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        let data = items[indexPath.row]

        cell.displayProductName.text = data.productName

        cell.buttonAction = { sender in
            print("Button tapped...")
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

**Custom Cell**

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    var buttonAction: ((UIButton) -> Void)?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    @IBAction func activeInactive(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.buttonAction?(sender)
    }
}
```

**Table View**

[image]

How can I animate the width of the row where the button was tapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subclass `UIButton` and add an `index` property where you can store the represented index for the button:

```
import UIKit

class UIButtonWithIndex: UIButton {

    var representedIndex: Int?

}
```

Then you should use this class in the storyboard instead `UIButton`.

After that add the button as an outlet in your cell and connect in in Interface Builder.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButtonWithIndex!

    var buttonAction: ((UIButtonWithIndex) -> Void)?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    @IBAction func activeInactive(_ sender: UIButtonWithIndex) {
        self.buttonAction?(sender)
    }

    // Reset the represented index when reusing the cell
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        //Reset content view width
        button.representedIndex = nil
    }
}
```

Then when you dequeue the cell in `cellForRowAt indexPath` set the `representedIndex` property. Now in your buttonAction you should have the index of the row in which the button was tapped.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reusableCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    let data = items[indexPath.row]

    cell.displayProductName.text = data.productName

    cell.button.representedIndex = indexPath.item
    cell.buttonAction = { sender in
        print("Button tapped... \(sender.representedIndex)")
    }

    return cell
}
```

Once you have the index you can retrieve the cell with [cellForRowAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrowatindexpath?language=objc)

Comment: I will give this a try and let you know. Quick question thoug, where did `item` come from? Thanks.

Comment: It's the same as indexPath.row https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765730/nsindexpath-item-vs-nsindexpath-row

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot!. FYI - This is how I retrieved the cell... `let currentCell = self.myTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row:sender.representedIndex!, section: 0))`

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to:

1. Create subview, let's call it "resizeableContentView"
2. Add "resizeableContentView" as a child to cell's "contentView"
3. Add your views to "resizeableContentView" as a child
4. Set .clearColor for cell and "contentView" background color if needed
5. Set width for "resizeableContentView" by action
6. Don't forget reset cell when it's reused

Answer (score 1):

you can try this boilerplate code:

```
cell.buttonAction = { sender in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                cell.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 50)
            }
        }
```

Comment: @ cagri colak - But how do I get the selected row in method `cellForRowAt indexPath:` ? I need to know what row was tapped.

Comment: like this:

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 50)
        }
        
    }

Comment: But I'm not tapping the row directly, I have a button inside the the cell that will be tapped. See, `LorenzOliveto`'s solution.